# create n values from final calculated answer in excel 365

Tags: excel

I am attempting to create a graph with out data history. In other words, I am making a spreadsheet that allows someone to enter in parameters such as voltage, amp hours, and calculate some totals. There is no data other than direct answers.

My problem, is I want to graph the battery over time using a scatter plot, but I only have two data points: total run time and recommended run time.

So, I thought I could just create a set of data points based on "total run time and recommended run time".

ex: if I have 80 hours, I want to create roughly 80 data points to represent current at that time point.

I feel like just programming something in C++ or python, might be easier for this simulation, however, I am making this for a sales person to gather quick info for customers. Any help, would be kindly appreciated.

-Smitty

Found the '`sequence()`' formula in excel, but it is not released yet for excel 365. Haven't found any other formulas that can do what I need.

Comment: You best have some sample data with a screenshot for us to better understand the situation of your question. Also provide expected output.

Comment: Thank you. I was not allowed to post a picture because this was my first post.[img]https://i.imgur.com/CrN9TQ7.png[/img]

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA in excel I was able to produce data points based off my answer:

```
Sub AddSerialNumbers()

Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo Last

i = InputBox("Enter Value", "Enter Serial Numbers")

For i = 1 To i

ActiveCell.Value = i

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Next i

Last:Exit Sub

End Sub
```